# При добавлении зависимости в проект MAVEN и развертывании на GLASSFISH вылетает ERROR

Tags: java, java-ee, maven, glassfish

В web проекте **Java** есть 2 объекта типа *String* - ***JSON*** и ***JSONSchema***. Пытаюсь проверить соответствует ли json схеме. 
Добавляю в зависимости проекта **Maven** -  **Jackson**. Он работает в связке вот с этой либой:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Как только добавляю зависимости этой либы, проект перестает деплоится.
В качестве локального сервера использую **GlassFish**.

**ERROR**:

```
java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
```

Пробовал другие версии, не помогло.

Такая проблема **сразу после** добавления зависимости.

Если написать код и протестировать вне сервера, все работает.

Пример кода:

```
public static boolean validate(String jsonData, String jsonSchema) {
        try {
            JsonNode schema = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonSchema);
            JsonNode data = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonData);

            final JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
            JsonValidator validator = factory.getValidator();

            ProcessingReport report = validator.validate(schema, data);
            return report.isSuccess();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR WHILE VALIDATING JSON WITH SCHEMA");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` говорит о том, что в момент компиляции кода класс был, а в рантайме его нет. У `json-schema-validator` (если верить его [pom.xml в maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-validator/2.2.6/jar)) есть зависимость от библиотеки `yoda-time` (на класс именно из этой библиотеки ругается)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Видимо, для корректной работы выбранного Вами валидатора, Вам нужно добавить в свои зависимости и эту библиотеку.

Comment: Не помогло. Пишет все то же самое. Более того, если добавить только лишь joda-time в зависимости, эффект такой же.

Comment: @Donatello, Вам нужно донести эту библиотеку до GlassFish, чтобы она загрузилась в classpath приложения. Вы приложение через maven деплоите?

Comment: Да. Добавляю зависимости автоматически, на всякий случай руками делаю clean + package, после чего делаю деплой из Intellij Idea

Comment: @Donatello, если у Вас `war` деплоится, Вам необходимо добиться, чтобы эта библиотека (joda-time) попала в каталог `WEB-INF/libs`. Я не силён в GlassFish, но уверен, что можно и в него как-то эту либу "затолкать". Копайте в эту сторону.

Comment: Деплоится war, и в нем действительно в WEB-INF/libs лежат обе эти либы

Comment: @Donatello и происходит такая же ошибка при деплое?

Comment: Да, если убрать из зависимостей и пересобрать, ошибки нет

Comment: Не стоит прогибаться под изменчивый мир, жсон схема вещь сырая

Comment: Так и не понял в чем конкретно была проблема, но очевидно в сборке или конфигурации самого приложения. Создал проект через Spring Boot Initialzr, всё работает